# AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'createFisherFaceRecognizer'

Tags: python, opencv, face-recognition

I have installed opencv-python and then tried this piece of code:

*

```
import cv2
import glob as gb
import random
import numpy as np
#Emotion list
emojis = ["neutral", "anger", "contempt", "disgust", "fear", "happy", "sadness", "surprise"] 
 #Initialize fisher face classifier
fisher_face = cv2.createFisherFaceRecognizer()
```

*

But I was getting this error. I tried installing opencv-contrib-python but again it gave me the same issue.Kindly help me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure this is the exact code you tried to run?  I don't see why it would refer to `'cv2.cv2'`.

Comment: import cv2
import glob as gb
import random
import numpy as np
#Emotion list
emojis = ["neutral", "anger", "contempt", "disgust", "fear", "happy", "sadness", "surprise"] 
 #Initialize fisher face classifier
fisher_face = cv2.createFisherFaceRecognizer()

Comment: I want to train an emotion classifier . so I need FisherFace which is available in opencv

Comment: Don't put code in comments. Edit your question and paste the code there and use the formatting tools.

Comment: @JitendarpalSingn have you tried out my solution?

Comment: Yes,,Thanks its working:)

Answer (score 1):

Chances are you are using *OpenCV 3.3* and according to their [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d2/de9/classcv_1_1face_1_1FisherFaceRecognizer.html), this module was moved under `face`. You can access it with `cv2.face.FisherFaceRecognizer_create()`